# geolocation.watchPosition() not working in Ionic 4

Tags: location, ionic4

I am learner in Ionic and present in my application I am trying to get user location using below code but it's not working properly.

I mean **lat** and **longs** are coming but very slowly location lat and longs changing when user move one place to another. Is there any better solution for getting user current location?

```
 this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });

    let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log("----->Watch latitude" + data.coords.latitude);
        console.log("-----> Watch logitude" + data.coords.longitude)
        console.log("-----> Watch accuracy" + data.coords.accuracy)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the accuracy by passing the enableHighAccuracy option:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true })
```

or

```
this.geolocation.watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout: 10000 })
```

You can also pass params for increasing the frequency the call is made such as **timeout**, this is explained in the README:

"enableHighAccuracy: Provides a hint that the application needs the best possible results. By default, the device attempts to retrieve a Position using network-based methods. Setting this property to true tells the framework to use more accurate methods, such as satellite positioning. (Boolean)

timeout: The maximum length of time (milliseconds) that is allowed to pass from the call to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition or geolocation.watchPosition until the corresponding geolocationSuccess callback executes. If the geolocationSuccess callback is not invoked within this time, the geolocationError callback is passed a PositionError.TIMEOUT error code. (Note that when used in conjunction with geolocation.watchPosition, the geolocationError callback could be called on an interval every timeout milliseconds!) (Number)

maximumAge: Accept a cached position whose age is no greater than the specified time in milliseconds. (Number)"

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: { enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout: 10000 } is this enough to get lat and longs in android ddevice?

Comment: Yes, it should work on your device just as it would with the code in your initial post, just pass these option params to increase the accuracy and frequency of the calls to retrieve the position, greater accuracy should give you lat and longs with more significant digits.

Comment: You can decrease the number for timeout if you want the call to happen more frequently.

Comment: i will put 5000

Comment: This is a cordova plugin, they typically need to be on a device to work since they leverage the native functionality of the mobile device, that is not going to happen on a desktop browser. 

If you want to get location via the desktop browser on a web app there are other methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189501/discussion-between-abhiram-and-jay-ordway).

Comment: Error getting location 
PositionError {code: 2, message: "Network location provider at 'googleapis.com' : No response received."} 
code: 2 
message: "Network location provider at 'googleapis.com' : No response received." 
__proto__: PositionError

Comment: Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received

Comment: I would try to test on the device and difference browsers, it may be a chrome issue:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=geolocation&colspec=ID

Comment: Please check and let me know

Comment: @jay Ordway:- sir i tried ur code it's working but not in all android device.like:not working in oppo F11pro but in another Android device watchPosition it's fire anything why